# How to convert String to List in Groovy

Tags: groovy, titan, gremlin

I'm having problem converting the Strings "[3]" here:

```
  p = {"results":["[3]","[3]"],"success":true,"version":"2.4.0","queryTime":63.102287}
```

to Lists.

p[0] gives me:

```
 {"results":["[3]"],"success":true,"version":"2.4.0","queryTime":68.24303}
```

So I was thinking I could use Eval.me(p[0]) but thet gives me an error saying:

```
  {"message":"","error":"javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static groovy.util.Eval.me() is applicable for argument types: (com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.GremlinGroovyPipeline) values: [[GremlinStartPipe, GraphQueryPipe(has,vertex), IdentityPipe, PropertyPipe(Sannolikhet), RangeFilterPipe(0,0)]]\nPossible solutions: me(java.lang.String), me(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.lang.String), is(java.lang.Object), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), _(groovy.lang.Closure), dump()","api":{"description":"evaluate an ad-hoc Gremlin script for a graph.","parameters":{"rexster.returnKeys":"an array of element property keys to return (default is to return all element properties)","rexster.showTypes":"displays the properties of the elements with their native data type (default is false)","load":"a list of 'stored procedures' to execute prior to the 'script' (if 'script' is not specified then the last script in this argument will return the values","rexster.offset.end":"end index for a paged set of data to be returned","rexster.offset.start":"start index for a paged set of data to be returned","params":"a map of parameters to bind to the script engine","language":"the gremlin language flavor to use (default to groovy)","script":"the Gremlin script to be evaluated"}},"success":false}
```

Anyone that knows how this can be done without using Eval.me?

**EDIT**

To Clarify, the first part of my script:

```
 p = g.V('containerName','CvsRisk').outE.inV.hasNot('Sannolikhet',null).'Sannolikhet';
```

I "extract" all the vertices in a container with the containerName CvsRisk that has a property named "Sannolikhet" that is not null.
Running this part of the script gives me the following response from the server:

```
  {"results":["[3]","[3,3]","[3,3]","[3,3]","[3,3]","[3,3]","[3,3]","[3]","[3,3]","[3]","[3,3]","[3,3]"],"success":true,"version":"2.4.0","queryTime":20.429118}
```

Which is what I want since all my properties named "Sannolikhet" contains an array of values.

It is from here I want to iterate through the result and sum up the values in the Strings, but in order to do so I need to convert the Strings to lists.

Comment: so what code are you using right now?

Comment: I've tried using Eval.me but that does not work, or what do you mean?

Comment: 1st of all, you are converting an instance of `GremlinGroovyPipeline` class here, and not the `String`. so, the 1st thing you need to do is `Eval.me(p[0].toString())`

Comment: if the shown code there (which more looks like json) is the toString, then this will not work.  i'd rather assume, that there is a trivial api to get the results.  like p.results.

Comment: I just sat the variable p here to the result I get from the server after running my code to explain my problem. I've tried p.results but that gived an error saying: "message":"","error":"java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Element"

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can parse the resulting JSON with `JsonSlurper` and</strike> collect the `results` with `Eval` applied. If you are sure there is no method ready to get the value in gremlin, then i guess you have to work with something like this:

**Update:** on a second thought, `p.results` should probably work fine, forget the first two commented lines:

```
//result='{"results":["[3]","[3,3]","[3,3]","[3,3]","[3,3]","[3,3]","[3,3]","[3]","[3,3]","[3]","[3,3]","[3,3]"],"success":true,"version":"2.4.0","queryTime":20.429118}'

//json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText result

p = ["results":["[3]","[3,3]","[3,3]","[3,3]","[3,3]","[3,3]","[3,3]","[3]","[3,3]","[3]","[3,3]","[3,3]"]]

assert p.results.size() == 12

vertices = p.results.collect { Eval.me(it) }

assert vertices.size() == 12

assert vertices[0] == [3]
assert vertices[1] == [3, 3]
assert vertices[-3] == [3]
assert vertices[-1] == [3, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but p.results does not work. Doing p.results gives me an error saying "message":"","error":"java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Element"

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution

The whole solution is:

```
  def p = g.V('containerName','CvsRisk').outE.inV.hasNot('Sannolikhet',null).'Sannolikhet';
  m= [];for(i in p){m.add(Eval.me(i));};k=m.sum();k*.toInteger().sum()
```